# Can Moses enter the holy of holies?

Tags: exodus, numbers, moses

In Exodus 25:22

> There I will meet with you; and from above the atoning cover, from between the two cherubim which are upon the ark of the testimony, I will speak to you about every commandment that I will give you for the sons of Israel.

and in Numbers 7:89 (NASB)

> Now when Moses entered the tent of meeting to speak with Him, he heard the voice speaking to him from above the atoning cover that was on the ark of the testimony, from between the two cherubim; so He spoke to him.

Can Moses enter the holy of holies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between Moses and the atoning cover was the curtain.

Hebrews 9:7

> But only the high priest entered the inner room, and that only once a year, and never without blood, which he offered for himself and for the sins the people had committed in ignorance.

No exception, not even Moses. That is until Jesus shed his blood on the cross.

> Matthew 27:50 And when Jesus had cried out again in a loud voice, he gave up his spirit.
> 51At that moment the curtain of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom. The earth shook, the rocks split

Now the way to the holy of the holies is open to us all the time anytime without sacrificing more blood other than the blood of Jesus.

Hebrews continues in 10:19

> Therefore, brothers and sisters, since we have confidence to enter the Most Holy Place by the blood of Jesus,

Comment: I think the question lacks clarity and the answer too because the question references the Old Testament texts and the answer is also based on New Testament text explaining the same OT situation. How do you see answer from the perspective of Heb. 10:19 saying, “Therefore, brethren, having boldness to enter the holiest by the blood of Jesus Christ, ...”?

Answer (score 0):

Even Moses was not exempted from staying off the Holies of Holies.

"This shall be a continual burnt offering throughout your generations at the door of the tabernacle of the congregation before the LORD: where I will meet you, to speak there unto thee." [Exodus 29:42]

Although God would speak to Moses from the mercy seat which was between the cherubims, he had to stay outside the tabernacle, because the mercyseat and the ark of covenant were in the holies of holies.

Comment: @ The Torah said that God met with Moses in his own tent outside the camp, not in the Holy of Holies. Only the High Priest was allowed to enter there once a year (Aaron, at the time of Moses's life).  Your last sentence has a mistaken word:  "Aaron" should have been mentioned, not Moses.  Yes, Moses could not enter the Holy of Holies.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!